# Blocking nested-loops iterator

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to port the following Python generator to a Java `Iterator`:

```
def gen_sums(blocks1, blocks2):
  for b1 in blocks1:
    for b2 in blocks2:
      for n1 in b1:
        for n2 in b2:
          yield n1 + n2
```

In the Java version, the interfaces look like:

```
public class Block {
  ...

  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() { ... }
}

public class GenSums implements Iterator<Integer> {
  private Iterator<Block> blocks1;
  private Iterator<Block> blocks2;

  ...

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() { /* TODO */ }

  @Override
  public Integer next() { /* TODO */ }
}
```

...which I've found extremely hard to get right. There are simply a lot of states to store in the `GenSums` class, and to resume from. Is there any "standard" way to implement this kind of iterators in Java? I'd like to avoid using third-party libraries.

Comment: See https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.Set...-   If you don't want to use a library, you must keep the states and reset the "internal" iterators yourself.

Comment: (of course you could always copy the source of just that function...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 then you might want to consider producing a stream rather than an iterator. A stream can be converted into an iterator if required (using `BaseStream.iterator()`).

So, for example:

```
class Block {
    private final int[] b;

    public IntStream getBs() {
        return Arrays.stream(b);
    }
}

public IntStream generate(List<Block> block1, List<Block> block2) {
    return block1.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(b1 -> block2.stream()
            .flatMapToInt(b2 -> b1.getBs()
                .flatMap(n1 -> b2.getBs().map(n2 -> n1 + n2)));
}
```

As you can see that is pretty close to the equivalent in Python - the `for` statements become `flatMap` and the `yield` becomes a `map`.

Comment: You'll need to use `flatMapToInt()` for `b1` and `b2`.

Comment: The last line should be `flatMap()` since it's already an `IntStream`.

Comment: The first one should also be `flatMapToInt()`.